# Adding Dtrace on Java

Tags: java, macos, solaris, dtrace

How can I add a DTrace probe inside a java code so that I can fire it and profile it on OS X?
I tried com.sun.tracing framework which works well in Solaris, but not supported in OSX.

Comment: http://dtrace.org/guide/chapter.html ,this site explains thoroughly what u are asking i believe u will find your answer if you read it, sorry ur right

Comment: If I'm reading [this blog post entry](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/MacOSXPort/Mac+OS+X+Port+Using+HotSpot+DTrace+Probes) correctly, you don't have JSDT probes on Mac OS X. You're probably [better off using btrace](https://kenai.com/projects/btrace) in this case.